# Only require constraint in HAVING clause if condition in WHERE clause is false

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php application that lets people search for data by adding filters. A query will be automatically generated based on their input.
So for example, they could add a filter for `Date is greater than` which is required.
Then they could also add several filters where at least one of those filters have to be required.
This works fine, however, the issue is that some of the filters depend on aggregate functions such as `SUM` which needs to be put into the `HAVING` clause. This essentially breaks the search logic as we can no longer match that filter up against the other ones separated by `OR`.

In the below example, they want to find all people with these filters:

Date greater than 2015
AND
(Person is Johnny OR product is Vaccination OR total expense is greater than 10)

```
SELECT
    SUM(expense) as total
FROM
    people
JOIN
    expense ON expense.person = id
WHERE
        expense.date > 2015
    AND
        (person = 'Johnny' OR product = 'Vaccination')
GROUP BY
    id
HAVING
    (total > 10) -- Only want to require this constraint if the conditions in WHERE brackets clause are false
```

Since one of the filters use an aggregate function we are unable to match it up against the other filters.

I've tried putting the where condition as a column in the SELECT and do an IF on the HAVING if that column is false. This works, but is not optimal, and will break in many cases as this query will have to be automatically generated.

Have anyone got a good suggestion of how I should approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql allows HAVING being used as a WHERE,so move all your WHERE conditions to HAVING

```
HAVING
        expense.date > 2015
    AND (
        (person = 'Johnny' OR product = 'Vaccination')
   OR (total > 10) )
```

Comment: I would need to select all of the columns which are required so it can be used in HAVING, which might have some performance impact, but other than that, I guess this would work. Cheers